# vacuumlo is not reclaiming space occupied by unused LOBs

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table where I store some images. Recently I had to run some tests where I had to delete all rows of said table and then insert new rows again, so I had to import the same images multiple times. After I finished it I noticed it took up a lot of space in my drive, so I tried running `vacuumlo` to reclaim this space, but nothing happened. The program finished running with no errors and a message saying

> "0 objects found"

or something like that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/vacuumlo.html):

> vacuumlo is a simple utility program that will remove any "orphaned"
>   large objects from a PostgreSQL database. An orphaned large object
>   (LO) is considered to be any LO whose OID does not appear in any oid
>   or lo data column of the database.

**You can check orphains manually, joining `pg_largeobject` against all your lo tables.** Eg: lets create couple of lo tables and fill them with data:

```
b=# create table l_o (n text, o oid);
CREATE TABLE
b=# create table lo (n text, p oid);
CREATE TABLE
b=# insert into l_o values('one',lo_import ('/tmp/wheel.PNG'));
INSERT 0 1
b=# insert into l_o values('two',lo_import ('/tmp/wheel.PNG'));
INSERT 0 1
b=#  insert into l_o values('three',lo_import ('/tmp/wheel.PNG'));
INSERT 0 1
b=#  insert into lo values('one',lo_import ('/tmp/wheel.PNG'));
INSERT 0 1
b=#  insert into l_o values('two',lo_import ('/tmp/wheel.PNG'));
INSERT 0 1
```

Now check orphains:

```
b=# with l_o as (select o,'l_o' tname from l_o union all select p,'lo' from lo)
b-# select distinct loid, o, tname
b-# from pg_largeobject left outer join l_o on l_o.o = loid;
 loid  |   o   | tname
-------+-------+-------
 34530 | 34530 | lo
 34528 | 34528 | l_o
 34527 | 34527 | l_o
 34529 | 34529 | l_o
 34531 | 34531 | l_o
(5 rows)
```

None. and now with `vacuumlo`:

```
b=# \! vacuumlo -v -n b
Connected to database "b"
Test run: no large objects will be removed!
Checking o in public.l_o
Checking p in public.lo
Would remove 0 large objects from database "b".
```

Same. Now reproduce your case - drop,recreate and refill one on tables:

```
b=# drop table lo;
DROP TABLE
b=# create table lo (n text, p oid);
CREATE TABLE
b=# insert into lo values('one',lo_import ('/tmp/wheel.PNG'));
INSERT 0 1
```

Dry run:

```
b=# \! vacuumlo -v -n b
Connected to database "b"
Test run: no large objects will be removed!
Checking o in public.l_o
Checking p in public.lo
Would remove 1 large objects from database "b".
```

Check `pg_largeobject`:

```
b=# with l_o as (select o,'l_o' tname from l_o union all select p,'lo' from lo)
select distinct loid, o, tname
from pg_largeobject left outer join l_o on l_o.o = loid;
 loid  |   o   | tname
-------+-------+-------
 34528 | 34528 | l_o
 34531 | 34531 | l_o
 34550 | 34550 | lo
 34527 | 34527 | l_o
 34529 | 34529 | l_o
 34530 |       |
(6 rows)
```

Yes - one orphain (the "lo" table had one row, dropping and refilling made one row orphain)

run `vacuumlo` to fix it:

```
b=# \! vacuumlo -v b
Connected to database "b"
Checking o in public.l_o
Checking p in public.lo
Successfully removed 1 large objects from database "b".
```

Checking the result:

```
b=# with l_o as (select o,'l_o' tname from l_o union all select p,'lo' from lo)
select distinct loid, o, tname
from pg_largeobject left outer join l_o on l_o.o = loid;
 loid  |   o   | tname
-------+-------+-------
 34528 | 34528 | l_o
 34531 | 34531 | l_o
 34550 | 34550 | lo
 34527 | 34527 | l_o
 34529 | 34529 | l_o
(5 rows)
```

Yes - all clear. And now checking with `vacuumlo`:

```
b=# \! vacuumlo -v -n b
Connected to database "b"
Test run: no large objects will be removed!
Checking o in public.l_o
Checking p in public.lo
Would remove 0 large objects from database "b".
```

Comment: Sadly AWS RDS is not currently allowing it. But find [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174663/48347) my workaround for that disallowance.